# Es posible hacer un comment box sin Bases de Datos?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Estaba buscando si es posible hacer una sección en la que los comentarios se guarden en un .txt, y cada vez que se comente se actualice dicho archivo, solamente con javascript y php.

Comment: Hola Lisandro, bienvenido a Stack Overflow, te sugiero completar el [tour] para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También puedes revisar la sección de **[ask]** para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A tu pregunta si se puede , Yes we can , just do it !! :9

> Lo primero es lo primero , BUSCA EN GOOGLE :)

Te lo escribiré en PHP.

Crear fichero nuevo  y escribir , esto sobre escribe el contenido del fichero

```
$file = fopen("archivo.txt", "w");
fwrite($file, "Esto es una nueva linea de texto" . PHP_EOL);
fwrite($file, "Otra más" . PHP_EOL);
fclose($file);
```

Crear fichero nuevo  y escribir , esto edita ( No sobre escribe ) contenido del fichero

```
    $file = fopen("archivo.txt", "a");
    fwrite($file, "Añadimos línea 1" . PHP_EOL);
    fwrite($file, "Añadimos línea 2" . PHP_EOL);
    fclose($file);
```

Leer el fichero

```
    if (file_exists('archivo.txt')) {
        $file = fopen("archivo.txt", "r");
        while (!feof($file)) {
            echo fgets($file) . "<br />";
        }
        fclose($file);
    } else {
        echo 'file no exist';
    }
```